# AWS Cognito: update JWT ID token on user's attribute change

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to add to the token's payload a specific attribute. This attribute can be changed rarely (once per month), however I would like that the tokens would be updated immediately after this change.

WORKFLOW

In web/mobile app, user opens a profile view and changes attribute X. The current value of this attribute is also stored in ID token. So when user submit edits, the new value of X should be saved on the backend and should replace the old value in ID token. It is important, because attribute X determines whether user can or cannot do specific things in app.

What does Cognito do when payload's attribute change? It sends new version of JWT ID token in the next request?

Should I use refresh token? Or force to sign-out and sign-in user?

Answer (score 2):

Refresh token will be more appropriate in this usecase. Currently, refresh token flow is not exposed in the high level android SDK for user pools because it is done behind the scene by the SDK. For now, you might have to call the refresh token from low level SDK to get around this. 
(I am a developer from Amazon Cognito team,  we will take this as a feature request to allow this from our high level SDKs.)

Comment: We have the same use case. What do you mean by "call the refresh token from low level SDK"? Do you mean some way to force the `getSession` call to get a new ID token as opposed to just returning the cached session?